# How do you set wmode=opaque using Youtube's HTML5 iframe API?

Tags: api, html, youtube

I'm embedding Youtube's experimental HTML5 iframe capabilities in a website through use of the javascript API:

[YouTube Player API Reference for <ifram> Embeds](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html)

I'm aware of the z-index issues this brings about, and the fix that involves adding wmode=opaque (or wmode=transparent) to the iframe url:

[Fixed. My Youtube iframe z-index is ignored and is above a fixed div](http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix)

When just using the javascript API, how do you set wmode to opaque:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var player;
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
        // if I try adding wmode: opaque here, it breaks
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0 ,
            modestbranding: 1
            // if I try adding wmode: opaque as a playerVar here, it breaks
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange
        }
    });
 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Hmmmm...

Well, it appears I was hasty in posting the question. It appears that the correct form for setting wmode within the API is:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var player;
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0 ,
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: "opaque"
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange
        }
    });
 }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it is the default to be `opaque`. I tested changing `wmode` to `transparent`, `opaque` and removed it. When it wasn't specified it was automatically set to `opaque`.

I'm not sure if this always was the case, but it definitely is now.

Also remember this only applies when using the Flash player. You can disable the HTML 5 player to test this which is the default with the ['Disable Youtube™ HTML5 Player' plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-youtube-html5-pla/enmofgaijnbjpblfljopnpdogpldapoc?hl=en). Then just inspect element and drill down till you find the EMBED tag.